# Android notification text length on API<16

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to get the maximum number of message's characters in the notification bar on API less than 16 (where message is shown on the single line)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dude the notification length will depend on the screen size for that circumstance, so bigger the screen  more text will be shown otherwise the rest will appear as "..."

Comment: I know about that, so I need some kind of method, that will return the maximum number of characters in this device, but I can't find any info about it. So I just wanna know is it possible or are there any solutions to calculate this.

Comment: That is going to be very complex and very time wasting because of the fact that android has so much screens size and within those same screen sizes different ppi etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Increase android notification text length on API<16 ?

The straight answer is NO. because Android system has its own standards and due to some limits, it wont allow the notifications to be too big. However it depends on the device also. The notification size might vary according to the device screen size.

For your information,
JellyBean has provided with a feature something like this, [Expandable Notifications](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html). The [official Doc](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) says,

> With Jelly Bean you have the option to provide more event detail. You
>   can use this to show the first few lines of a message or show a larger
>   image preview. This provides the user with additional context, and -
>   in some cases - may allow the user to read a message in its entirety.
>   The user can pinch-zoom or two-finger glide in order to toggle between
>   base and expanded layouts. For single event notifications, Android
>   provides two expanded layout templates (text and image) for you to
>   re-use in your application.